# Pulsating/moving back light behind a shape

Tags: animation, lighting

I'm trying to create this type of lighting effect, behind or to outline, a logo in blender. The idea is to have the light animated so its either moving or pulsating as well.

I've tried cutting the logo out of a plane and positioning lights behind both objects to try and have light seeping through but I'm not having a lot of success from that. Does any one know of a good way to create this type of look? Thanks

[image]

Comment: You have several solutions: In the Compositor with Sun Beam for the first image, or create god rays with the help of volumetrics, or fake the rays with meshes

Comment: Hello. I think these particular effects are done in screen space after the rendering was done as a post-production effect (or compositor in Blender). Explore the "Glare" node for such effects.. In order to achieve these effects via a regular lighting rig and physically-based rendering you'll have to add a volumetric fog that will refract light in a way that will be hard to control, will make your render times longer and introduce a lot of artifacts or fireflies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *Compositor*. First create your scene, for example a hole in a plane, a lid, some lights underneath:

[image]

Render the image. Open the *Compositor*, create this kind of setup with a *Filter > Glare* node as suggested by Gorgious, and also a *Sun Beams* node (it needs a *Color > Alpha Over* to be mixed), you can move the center of the beams: keep the node selected and move the cross, or simply move the node parameters:

[image]

Here is what it gives:

[image]

Comment: Thank you - that was exactly what I was after :)

Thanks all for your feedback